# How do I compile my Javascript assets with webpack for Wallaby feature tests?

Tags: javascript, webpack, phantomjs, elixir, wallaby

I'm using Wallaby in a dummy Phoenix project that uses webpack to compile assets.

But I get this error:

```
1) test users have names (MyApp.Web.LandingPagesTest)
     test/my_app/web/integration/landing_pages/landing_pages_test.exs:6
     ** (Wallaby.JSError) There was an uncaught javascript error:

     Could not find component Website.
       mountComponents (http://localhost:4001/js/index.js:71740)
       (anonymous function) (http://localhost:4001/js/index.js:71759)
```

This is obviously being caused by my assets not being compiled.

How can I run webpack to compile my assets for Wallaby to use in phantomjs?

Answer (score 0):

I just add a line into `test_helper.exs` that compiles the assets

```
ExUnit.start()
{:ok, _} = Application.ensure_all_started(:wallaby)
Application.put_env(:wallaby, :base_url, XmsWeb.Endpoint.url())
System.cmd("cd", ["assets", "&&", "./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"])
```

now when you `mix test` they should compile